# Remove link tag in the head tag using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to remove the link tag using ReactJS?

My Example

```
componentDidMount() {
   document.getElementsByTagName("link").remove();
}
```

or

```
componentDidMount() {
   document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].remove();
}
```

I have tried but it doesn't work, is there any other way to remove the link tag? sorry, i'm still a beginner in using ReactJS

Comment: Why would you want to remove a `<link />` tag?

Comment: Is the link node present on the page when the component mounts?

Comment: @Hamidreza, there's a page that I don't use css link, so I want to remove the link tag.

Comment: @Vadzim, yeah because I use Router